# Problems with uploading multiple MultipartFile using dio and image_picker

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, dio, imagepicker

I have 4 File images that picked by image_picker, and I pass it to my function as parameters

```
required File image1,
required File image2,
required List<File> images, //list of 2 images
```

I turn them into MultipartFile using fromFile() constructor

```
var img1 = await MultipartFile.fromFile(image1.path, filename: 'img1.jpg');
  var img2 = await MultipartFile.fromFile(image2.path, filename: 'img2.jpg');

  List<MultipartFile> listImages = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var value = await MultipartFile.fromFile(images[i].path, filename: 'image_$i.jpg');
    listImages.add(value);
  }
```

Then I pass them into a Map name "data" through key "files" as a List of MultipartFile

```
///Upload images
  final imagesUploadResponse = await _dioClient.postRequest(
    'uploads/images',
    parameters: {'lang': 'en'},
    contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
    data: {
      'files': <MultipartFile>[
        img1,
        img2,
        ...listImages,
      ],
      'type': 'member',
    },
  );
```

Then I use dio.post like this: I created a FormData using fromMap() constructor, the map is "data" that I mentioned above,

```
final FormData formData = FormData.fromMap(data, ListFormat.multiCompatible);
  inspect(formData);
  final response = await dio.post<Map<String, dynamic>>(
    baseUrl + url,
    queryParameters: parameters,
    data: formData,
    options: _getOption(token, contentType: contentType, boundary: formData.boundary),
  );
```

...and here is how I created my Options:

```
Options _getOption(String? token, {String? contentType, String? boundary}) {
return Options(
  headers: {
    'Content-Type':
        contentType == null ? '$contentType;boundary=$boundary' : 'application/json',
    if (token != null) 'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',

    //Optional
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
  },
);
```

}

The result is error code 422: unprocessable content

What is the problem?

I found out on Dio Package doc

> There are two ways to add multiple files to FormData, the only difference is that upload keys are different for array types

- Using fromMap() constructor, and key 'files' will turn into 'files[]' (This is how my API expected the request to be)

```
final formData = FormData.fromMap({
  'files': [
    MultipartFile.fromFileSync('path/to/upload1.txt', filename: 'upload1.txt'),
    MultipartFile.fromFileSync('path/to/upload2.txt', filename: 'upload2.txt'),
  ],
});
```

- Adding MapEntry, this way 'files' will not turn into 'files[]'

```
final formData = FormData();
formData.files.addAll([
  MapEntry(
   'files',
    MultipartFile.fromFileSync('./example/upload.txt',filename: 'upload.txt'),
  ),
  MapEntry(
    'files',
    MultipartFile.fromFileSync('./example/upload.txt',filename: 'upload.txt'),
  ),
]);
```

If I try the MapEntry way, my backend will consider 4 files as 1 file only (I tested on Postman, sending a 'files' array of 4 images behave the same problem, while sending a 'files[]' array of 4 images is right)

Answer (score 0):

As per your question description you are trying to upload 4 images & get all of them into array on api side am I right?

So in your flutter code make some little change & try

Change “files” to files[0] like below

```
final formData = FormData();
formData.files.addAll([
  MapEntry(
    'files[0]',
    MultipartFile.fromFileSync('./example/upload.txt',filename: 'upload.txt'),
  ),
  MapEntry(
    'files[1]',
    MultipartFile.fromFileSync('./example/upload.txt',filename: 'upload.txt'),
  ),
]);
```